# Image Processing: concaveHull to find defects of an image

Tags: python, image-processing, convex-hull, concave-hull, convexity-defects

I've been trying to identify a method to calculate defects (line roughness) and convexHull is the only real method I've found. This method does exactly what I want with the exception that it doesn't follow the curvature of the lines at all. Below is the image being analyzed with one convexHull plotted on it. I absolutely cannot find a concaveHull function which would fix the problem.

Is there a concaveHull function somewhere I can't find? I know there would be parameters such as sensitivity that would need optimized, but I don't know where to start. Here are the functions I'm referring to.

```
            hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints=True)
            hullDefects = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints=False)
            spiralDefects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hullDefects)
```

[image: ConvexHull problem]

Comment: What would such a function do? What is a concave hull? I think your question would be more useful if you asked for a way to detect whatever specific type of defect that you’re looking at.

Comment: Updated the question, I'm trying to find the roughness of the lines.

Comment: I googled for “line roughness” — this seems to be a term in microchip fabrication? “ When variations in the width of a resist feature occur quickly over the length of the feature, this variation is called linewidth roughness.” it would be good if you didn’t depend your question on application-specific terminology. Most people following the image-processing tag don’t know anything about microchip fabrication.

Comment: I'm not referring to any application-specific terminology, I simply want to quantify the how "rough" the line is in comparison to a perfectly smooth line. Meaning if you were to zoom in on the line, how rough is that. I can add a picture of what I am referring to if you think that would be useful.

Comment: Oh, so it's not about the variation in width, but about the deviation of the edges from smoothness. So maybe you want to smooth the outlines, and then quantify how much you modified them to get them to be smooth.

Comment: Yes that would be perfect, how would you smooth the edges?

Comment: I would probably get the outline as a polygon and then apply the Douglas-Peuker simplification algorithm.